# rtabmap_localization issue

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i'm using rtabmap and i'm pretty new to it. I'm noticing an unexpected behaviour where the algorithm is running continuously even when the robot is not moving, and it update the map->odom tf with differences under 10cm but often over 5-6 cm..
i've attached a video that illustrate this behaviour and also you can view the video here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5G6Ct8c7jq7NDNkbGcxMTI4Tlk.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252310/rtabmap_localization-issue/) by [aerydna](https://answers.ros.org/users/27607/aerydna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

see http://official-rtab-map-forum.206.s1.nabble.com/roswrapper-localization-issue-td2577.html

> This is normal, the localization transform is not always exactly the same, because of the noise of the sensor and to which image in the map it is actually localizing.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0